# Criar um registro e adicionar relacionamento através do httpPost do Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Ao criar um registro novo na aba eu preciso pegar o ID da minha tela principal e enviar junto com o novo objeto. Atualmente eu tenho esse código:

```cs
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMenuProduct(MenuProduct MenuProduct)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.MenuProducts.Add(MenuProduct);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        if (MenuProduct.MenuIdAux != null)
        {
            RelationshipMenuProductWithMenu relationship = new RelationshipMenuProductWithMenu
            {
                MenuProductId = MenuProduct.Id,
                MenuId = Convert.ToInt32(MenuProduct.MenuIdAux)
            };

            await AddRelationshipMenuProductWithMenu(relationship);
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = MenuProduct.Id }, MenuProduct);
    }
```

Neste caso eu adiciono `MenuIdAux` no model para enviar junto com o novo objeto o Id da minha tela principal. Como eu poderia criar esse relacionamento sem precisar adicionar esse parâmetro no meu model `MenuProduct`? Tentei passar como parâmetro no post mas o `HttpPost` não aceitava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duas maneiras:

### 1. Criando um ViewModel idêntico ao seu Model, com um parâmetro a mais

```
public class MenuProductViewMode {
    public int MenuIdAux { get; set; }

    // Coloque aqui os outros parâmetros do Model
}
```

Monte o Model dentro do método:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMenuProduct(MenuProductViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var menuProduct = new MenuProduct();
    // Faça todas as atribuições de viewModel para o seu Model aqui

    db.MenuProducts.Add(MenuProduct);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    ...
}
```

### 2. Passando como parâmetro da Action

Essa maneira não é tão boa quanto a primeira porque a variável é livre, mas funciona.

Coloque como argumento o seguinte:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMenuProduct(MenuProduct MenuProduct, int MenuIdAux) { ... }
```

Coloque no seu JSON de envio um campo chamado `MenuIdAux` que o *bind* será feito automaticamente.

Comment: Eu deveria criar um projeto para guardar minhas ViewModels e então compartilhar elas com o Web Api e o projeto Asp.Net MVC?

Comment: @CarlosGeovanio Pode ser feito desta forma, ou então as ViewModels podem ficar no projeto de API e o projeto de API ser referenciado pelo projeto MVC.